# Are there other ways of saying "We welcome <someone> to <do something>"

Tags: infinitives, politeness

I realize that by using *"to welcome"* **as a verb** followed immediately by a **to infinitive** like *"to do something"* is grammatically incorrect and oddly phrased.

Say:

> I welcome [someone] to [do something].

For example:

> We **welcome the media** and the press **to conduct** an interview with our CEO at the venue.
>
> We **welcome key delegates** worldwide **to partake** in this mega event of the year.

If these sound wrong, how would you restructure the sentence to make them right?

Comment: I don't think it's ungrammatical per se; however, I agree that it could sound strange in some (perhaps most) cases. The improve this question, we could use some examples you have in mind. (You can edit your own question to add more examples, details, and so on.)

Comment: I've reopened this question as the OP has provided us with required information. I think it's a good question.

Comment: Why do you think it's grammatically incorrect?  "We welcome you to join us" is a very commonly used phrase.  That said, I think saying **We invite you to X** is slightly more fluent-sounding.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest rephrasing would be to say "We **invite** you to do something or say something". Or "We **call upon you** or "**call upon so and so** to do something or say something.

Comment: *calling upon* someone to do something has a slightly more imperative context, versus *inviting* someone is usually friendly & encouraging (or occasionally sarcastic) and implies that the direct object is free to undertake the invitation at their convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: n.b This is the original answer to the original question.

"You are welcome to [do something]".

e.g. "You are welcome to take a seat".
"You are welcome to sit down".
"You are welcome to have a biscuit".
"You are welcome to try".

Comment: Vote retracted! The OP is asking *'...welcome **you** to do something'* and not 'you are welcome...'.

Comment: The OP is asking to make the person welcome.  Most actions benefit from the passive form.  

There is a much more limited set that can use the active form.

"I welcome you to sit down" would not ever be used, for example.

"I welcome you to join me" is the only use I can think of, offhand. In the active form, it would generally be a place, e.g. "I welcome you to my home"

Comment: This is the reason OP's asking - is it possible because it looks odd? The answer should be *yes* it is possible, but more context is needed. You changed the entire structure making it an obvious thing in the language.

Comment: Given that he asked for the *general* case - I gave the answer for the *general* case asked. There is only one specific exception to the general rule that I can think of.  And as you saw, I have now provided it in the commentary.

Comment: You need to edit the answer and explain it a bit more. You started off with the structure that is **not** asked anywhere. And you gave all the examples supporting it.

Comment: @Maulik, the question as asked was: "How would you restructure the sentence to make it sound right?".  The question was **not** what ways can a similar structure be valid for cases which do **not** match the situation  I am asking about.  I answered the question set - to provide a valid re-structuring.  Unless you are contending that this was an XY question?

Comment: I buy that. Would you mind adding this to your answer?

Comment: The question provides more information now. I have reopened it and you may want to revise this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me (native English speaker in the Northeast United States), these examples sound grammatically correct, but formal, and based on the examples you chose, this level of formality seems to fit. This phrasing would seem natural in a formal invitation or announcement. Part of this formality comes from the plural pronoun `We` and from the verb tenses that you pointed out.

**Alternatives**
To make this phrasing less awkward, change `I welcome [someone] to [do something].` to `[someone] is welcome to [do something].`

In a common-day setting, I would avoid the word `welcome` and instead say `could` or `can` or maybe even `allowed` depending on the context.

**Examples:**

- `The royal family welcomes you to attend the birthday celebration of Princess Minerva` Is grammatically correct and appropriate and might appear in fiction.
- `I welcome you to attend my birthday celebration.` Is grammatically correct but overly formal given the context.
- `You are welcome to attend my birthday celebration.` Is still formal and a little weird, but okay in the context. This might appear on a card or in writing. Probably someone wouldn't say it like this.
- `You can come to my birthday party.` Is a more every-day wording. Notice that the word `attend` was switched for `come` and `celebration` for `party`.

**Your Examples:**

`We welcome the media and the press to conduct an interview with our CEO at the venue.` could become:

- `The press is welcome to conduct an interview with our CEO at the venue.`
- `The press is allowed to conduct an interview with our CEO at the venue.`

`We welcome key delegates worldwide to partake in this mega event of the year.` could become:

- `Key delegates worldwide are welcome to partake in this mega event of the year.`
- `Key delegates worldwide can partake in this mega event of the year.`

Comment: Many thanks to you, Friendly Racoon.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is "We welcome [someone] to do something" grammatically wrong, it's also entirely unclear what it is the speaker means.

Do they mean "we invite [someone] to do something", "we would welcome [someone] doing something" (which is close to the same as "you are welcome to do something"], or "we welcome [the fact] that you [do/did/have done] something"?

So my answer would be to use something a little like one of the above structures, depending on what it is you want to say.

Comment: Why is grammatically wrong? Can you expand on that?

Comment: I explain that and why it's even worse than grammatically wrong in the second paragraph. It could mean any of at least three different things.

Comment: There are cases where it is not grammatically incorrect. "We welcome you to join us on Stack Exchange", for example, is a perfectly acceptable sentence, but in some cases it sounds weird to my American ears to hear "we welcome [someone] [infinitive]."

Comment: I sort of disagree, Tim. Just because something does not seem strange to our ear doesn't mean that it makes grammatical sense.  I have a little bit of the old-fashioned prescriptivism in my ideas about grammar, mind you, so ignore me if your philosophy is purely descriptivist.  In the example you give, you can always say the context clarifies what you mean, but I don't think the grammatical structure is right, for the reasons given above.